# Phonegap and Google Analytics are not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

I'm building an app with phonegap and wanted to use Google Analytics. I installed [this](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) plugin with the CLI and implemented the following lines of code into my `deviceReady` event:

```
analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-*******-5');
analytics.trackView('Frontsite');
```

(For sure I swapped the **** with my real tracking code).

Problem is I don't get an `error`, so I think the plugin works (or not), but the App is not tracked at all. When I go to the Google Analytics page where I created the mobile tracking property, it doesn't show my phone (or simulator) in the realtime-tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use plugin. You can directly call the google analytics API by using measurement protocol tracking id. It works fine in Andriod, IOS, Windows and Blackberry.

```
var dataform = {};
            dataform.v = 1;
            dataform.tid = "UA-xxxxxxxx-2";
            dataform.cid = "device id";
            dataform.t = "appview";
            dataform.an = "name";
            dataform.av = "0.0.1";
            dataform.cd = "Home Screen";
var url = "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect";
            $.ajax(url, {
                type: "post",
                contentType: "text/plain",
                data: dataform
            })
                    .done(function(result) {
                            alert("success");

                    })
                    .fail(function(error) {
                            alert("fail");

                    });
```

Comment: Do you have a link or something, maybe with a tutorial or explanation?

Comment: wow. thanks, works great. is this a common practice or a 'not so recommended'-way?