# Cordova 3.4-3.5: danwilson Google Analytics plugin Not Working

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, hybrid-mobile-app

i have a working PhoneGap/Cordova Project Ver 3.5.
i try to work with GA with this plugin, But without success:
https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

1. i success to install the plugin via this command:
   cordova plugin add https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git
2. when i try the usage the plugin it faild.
   for example:
   analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY') // UX-2323-23 for example

Any "analytics" function that i try to use fail with error:
"analytics is not defind"

1. i try via local server - get "analytics is not defind"
2. i try in simulator - get empty and white screen
3. i try on Real Device and also get empty and white screen

Please Help :)
Thanks,
Chen.R

Comment: Refer this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180238/phonegap-and-google-analytics-are-not-working/24180453#24180453

Answer (score 2):

First, provide access to external URL using in config.xml `<access origin="*" />` then
Put this `analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY')` into onDeviceReady function.

And then you can write your own page names like `analytics.trackView('page name');`

When you are on the google analytics account, please check the date and time set for view report on right side corner.